# Which mode to choose for do-release-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, ssh

There are two modes: "server" and "desktop". Can you use the "desktop" mode over text based ssh connection to upgrade a server which has some desktop environment as well? Or should you use the default server mode?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon

If what you want is the ssh service you can use on both Ubuntu Desktop and Server. The difference is that the Server is already installed and not on the Desktop, however with this command line can install and use the same way.

Installation command: `sudo apt install openssh-server`

Print the SSH server status: `sudo systemctl status ssh`

You should see something like active:

> active (running)

Comment: While it is true what you say, it doesn't exactly address the OP's question. The question is about the difference between `sudo do-release-upgrade --mode=server` and `sudo do-release-upgrade --mode=desktop`. The `ssh` part is just a side note: the OP wants to know whether it's _safe_ to issue one of those commands through an `ssh` connection (given the machine might reboot and/or restart the ssh service during the update process and as a result might loose the ssh connection).